# Gulp: Getting dest.on error when adding suffix to file name. Any ideas on how to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, gulp, preprocessor

I want to use Gulp to minify some .css files, rename theme to .min.css and move them to another directory.

For that I have set up the following (as per many tutorials I find online):

```
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const rename = require('rename');

gulp.task('mincss', () => {
  return gulp.src('css/*.css')
    .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/minified'));
});
```

However, this produces the error:

> TypeError: dest.on is not a function

I've Googled this but do not understand it.

It works fine if I remove rename pipe.

Would anyone know how to fix this?

(My Gulp version is  4.0.2)

Comment: I copied your code and it works perfectly.  Is this your entire gulpfile.js?  I suspect you just have a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of the actual `rename` dependency you are requiring. I believe it is `gulp-rename`, so your require should be `const rename = require('gulp-rename');`. Don't forget to do `npm install --save-dev gulp-rename` if you need to!